# External monitors not registering via Kensington dock on Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, kubuntu, docking-station

I have a work setup with two external monitors that are connected to my [Dell Latitude 7430](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/laptops-2-in-1-pcs/latitude-7430/spd/latitude-14-7430-2-in-1-laptop/s206l743014ukie_vp) laptop via a [Kensington SD3500v docking station](https://www.kensington.com/p/products/device-docking-connectivity-products/universal-docking-stations/sd3500v-5gbps-usb-3.0-dual-2k-docking-station-hdmidvi-ivga-windows-1/). The docking station makes use of DisplayLink technology. I run Kubuntu 22.10 on my laptop and have the latest [DisplayLink drivers](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu) installed.

However, although the laptop does register the mouse and keyboard through the dock, it does not recognize the external monitors. I have already tried connecting the dock via both the normal USB-A (2.0) port of my laptop and the USB-C port via an USB-A (3.0) to USB-C adapter.

On other (much older) laptops running Kubuntu, the setup does work and the external monitors do register. On those laptops it makes no difference whether I connect the dock via the USB-A 2.0 or 3.0 ports, both work fine. This shows that it is not a problem with the cable connectivity or operating system.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be with the Latitude laptop and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!